# CKEditor breaks when debug = False

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm nearing the end of my project, a blog. I have set `DEBUG = False` for security.

This breaks my CKEDITOR, making it just not appear at all when the page is loaded.

When `DEBUG = True` it works fine.

template:

```
<form class="text-center m-3" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button class="btn btn-signup right" id="button">Post &raquo;</button>
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm (forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('title', 'excerpt', 'featured_image',
              'content', 'author')

    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':
                                        'Give it a catchy title'}),
        'excerpt': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':
                                          'E.g. My first ever post'}),
        'content': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'placeholder':
                   '<p>Wrap your content in these P tags to create a paragraph</p> \
                    \n\n<b>Wrap your words in these B tags \
                    to make them bold</b>'}),
        'author': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': '',
                   'id': 'user', 'type': 'hidden'}),
    }
```

Comment: Django does not serve static/media files in production (`DEBUG = False`), for that same reson the `media` does not load: you need to configure Nginx/Apache/... or any other web server to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the fact that Django does *not* serve static files or media files in production. Indeed, As is specified in the [*Static file development view* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view):

> This view will only work if `DEBUG` is `True`.
>
> That’s because this **view is grossly inefficient and probably
> insecure**. This is only intended for local development, and **should
> never be used in production**.

Normally you should configure the `nginx`, `apache`, or other web server to serve static and media files. These web servers are likely more efficient and have more dedicated tooling for security. This is the main reason why Django is not supposed to serve static and media files in production.

Comment: I am currently using Cloudinary to serve the static files, but it is not working as intended. all images are served but it is just the ckeditor that is not.

Comment: @Jord: `{{ form.media }}`, will include `<link href="...">` and `<script src="...">` statements, so you need to load these files to the serving host as well. The idea of `{{ form.media }}` is that a form can thus add extra items that need to be loaded to the page

Comment: Okay, I'm not too sure on how to do this Willem. How do I go about loading these files to the serving host?

Comment: @Jord: you use `DEBUG = True`, inspect the source code of a form with the CKEditor, and upload the static files to cloundinary with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for you help Willem but I am still lost with it all. My head about to fall off. I will have another try some other time but right now I need to chill on couch lol.